# Why does a speedlite not fire when taking a still during movie mode?

Tags: flash, shutter-release, movie

My setup is limited to a Canon 6D and a Yongnuo flash, but I have a feeling this may be more fundamental than just the specific combination of body and flash.

When you set the camera to movie mode, you can still trigger a still picture capture with the shutter release. However, when you do this, an attached flash does not trigger. Why not?

Note, that this setup WILL fire the flash in live view mode.

(If I had to guess: rolling shutter in movie mode makes this impossible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 214 of the Canon 6D manual under Shooting Movies> Shooting Still Photos you will find:

> Even if an external Speedlite is used, it will not fire.

If you want full control of image parameters, you will have to switch out of movie mode and into standard still photo mode first. That is how Canon has designed the system.

Comment: In the end, this is the answer: it not designed to fire. But I am also curious if anyone has any insight into *why* they made this design decision.

Comment: I don't even understand why they allow still photos to be captured during movie mode in the first place. Seems pointless. I have never been capturing a movie and thought about capturing a still at the same time. They are two separate activities.